# How to group comma separated values into distinct sorted comma separated values

Tags: php, mysql, filtering, grouping, distinct

I’m trying to work out a piece of sql, and wondering if what I am attempting to do is possible, and if so how would I go about doing it? My goal is, if possible to return a thread id with all the unique values that are associated with that thread ID. In the example below, i show how far i have gotten and where I am attempt to get to.

```
$sql = SELECT `ThreadID`, `PostTags` FROM `ma_posts` WHERE `PostTags` IS NOT   NULL AND `PostTags` != '0' AND `PostTags` != ' ' ORDER BY `ThreadID`
```

RETURNS CURRENT RESULT
[image]

WANT TO RETURN A  FILTERED GROUPED RESULT OF DISTINCT VALUES SORTED ALPHABETICALLY

[image]

In the above example, the second instance of the name ‘Jon’ is removed from the names returned for ThreadID 14, and all of the names are condensed into one string/bit of data. The second and third instances of the name Barry and Mary are removed from the condensed ThreadID 20.

Is what I am attempting possible? If so how?

I’ve looked over Stackoverflow and the web and I’ve not found an example that really speaks to what I’m trying to do. Likely (hopefully) this is possible so i won’t then have to filter the coming in results via PHP. This will make life much simpler.

Thanks for any help as always folks
Cheers from the Monkee

Comment: Normalise your schema

Answer (score 1):

**You should really consider normalizing your schema. The solution will then be trivial.**

For now, you could try to convert the comma separated values into separate rows and then apply combination of UPPER, LOWER and SUBSTR to convert string's first character to upper case and rest to lower case (to convert "barry" into "Barry"). Finally apply GROUP_CONCAT with distinct and order by option to get the desired result.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    threadid,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT posttag
        ORDER BY posttag
        SEPARATOR ', ') posttags
FROM
    (SELECT 
        threadid,
            CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTR(posttag, 1, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTR(posttag, 2))) posttag
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        t.threadid,
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.posttags, ', ', t2.i), ', ', - 1) posttag
    FROM
        t
    JOIN (SELECT 1 i UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5) t2
    ON CHAR_LENGTH(t.posttags) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(t.posttags, ', ', '')) >= 2 * (t2.i - 1)) t) t
GROUP BY threadid;
```

You can always throw more `UNION ALL` in the subquery if there can be more than 5 values in posttags.

#### [Live Demo](http://rextester.com/WYZ94013)

Comment: @Strawberry - Thanks for your feedback. I've added a note in the answer.

Comment: I'm trying to slow your inexorable rise in rep :-)  - I think you're due to overtake me in about a week!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your database is not normalized. You need to normalized it into 3rd normal form. 
Anyhow you cant `distinct` word in your query, which will select unique values.

```
$sql = SELECT distinct `ThreadID`, `PostTags` FROM `ma_posts` WHERE `PostTags` IS NOT NULL 
AND `PostTags` != '0' AND `PostTags` != ' ' ORDER BY `ThreadID`
```

Comment: Until the schema is normalised, there is no 'anyhow'